# Reordering a binary search tree 'in place'

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I would like some helpful suggestions or code to implement a program that behaves according to:

1. Build a binary search tree from a sequence of integers on the command line (in the order given)
2. Re-orders the tree so that values appear in descending order, that is, the new tree has:

   - all values in left subtree are greater than root
   - all values in right subtree are less than root
   - this property applies over all nodes in the tree

The reordering must not involve building a new tree from the input integers (I have already achieved this); instead it must simply reorder them within the same tree.

This is my code so far that uses an incorrect approach (that is making two separate trees and inserting them using different rules).

```
typedef struct node{
    int value;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right; 
} NodeT;

NodeT *newNode(int);
NodeT *insertAscend(NodeT *, int);
NodeT *insertDescend(NodeT *, int);
void printTree(NodeT *, int);
void freeTree(NodeT *);

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    NodeT *t1 = NULL;
    NodeT *t2 = NULL;
    int i;
    int retval = 0;

    if(argc == 1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s integers ...\n", argv[0]);
        retval = 1;
    }else{
        int dataGood = 1;
        for(i =1; i < argc && dataGood; i++){
            int num;
            if(sscanf(argv[i], "%d", &num) != 1){
                fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s integers ...\n", argv[0]);
                freeTree(t1);
                freeTree(t2);
                dataGood = 0;
                retval = 1;
            }else{
                t1 = insertAscend(t1, num);
                t2 = insertDescend(t2, num);
            }
        }
        if(dataGood){
            printTree(t1, 0);

            printf("Swapped tree:\n");
            printTree(t2, 0);
            freeTree(t1);
            freeTree(t2);

        }
    }

    return retval;
}

NodeT *newNode(int v){
    NodeT *new;
    new = (NodeT *)malloc(sizeof(NodeT));
    assert(new != NULL);
    new->value = v;
    new->left = NULL;
    new->right = NULL;
    return new;
}

NodeT *insertAscend(NodeT *t, int v){
    if(t == NULL){
        t = newNode(v);
    }else if(v == t->value){
        ; // no duplicates
    }else if(v < t->value){
        t->left = insertAscend(t->left, v);
    }else if(v > t->value){
        t->right = insertAscend(t->right, v);
    }
    return t;
}

NodeT *insertDescend(NodeT *t, int v){
    if(t == NULL){
        t = newNode(v);
    }else if(v == t->value){
        ; // no duplicates
    }else if(v > t->value){
        t->left = insertDescend(t->left, v);
    }else if(v < t->value){
        t->right = insertDescend(t->right, v);
    }
    return t;
}

void printTree(NodeT *t, int depth){
    if(t != NULL){
        depth++;
        printTree(t->left, depth);
        int i;
        for(i = 1; i < depth; i++){
            putchar('\t');
        }
        printf("%d\n", t->value);
        printTree(t->right, depth);
    }
}

void freeTree(NodeT *t){
    if(t != NULL){
        freeTree(t->left);
        freeTree(t->right);
        free(t);
    }
}
```

Once againI am looking for help to simply reorder the BST in place without the creation of any new data structures. I can provide more clarification and some examples of desired out if my code below does not run for those willing to test. I am interested in this as I have seen this question used in previous interviews for companies and examinations and cannot seem to implement it effectively and according to their guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To re-order the tree, you can just swap the left and right subtrees of each node in the tree.

Comment: would a postfix fashion of traversing the BST work for this method?

Comment: The order shouldn't matter; you just need to hit every node.